# Eclipse Breakpoint System.out

Tags: java, eclipse

typically I set a breakpoint in my Java application when I want to observe the run.

However sometimes I just want to know if a method is called or not. Therefore a breakpoint does not help me, and I insert a "systrace" statement 
`System.out.println("method signature");`

I thought it would be a nice feature If I could set a breakpoint and when the breakpoint is reached to just print out the systrace message and continue the run.

Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: Why not you set a breakpoint in that method?

Comment: As @Tony said why don't you place a breakpoint in or on that method? If you place the breakpoint on the method signature it will be executed whenever that method is called independent of the line or whether there are other debug instructions in the code or not.

Comment: 1) I don't want the program to stop

Comment: 2) I don't want to manually insert code

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, but I don't know 'other debug instructions'. Any tutorial?

Comment: @matthias if you do not want to manually insert code, another approach you may like would be to use AspectJ to insert the additional methods you need.

Comment: @Tony sorry that was a typo, I meant "other debug information", i.e. line numbers etc. which might be removed by the compiler if told so.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to make it a conditional breakpoint with a following condition:

```
System.out.printf(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName() + "\n") == null
```

Works fine in my Eclipse. I'm using printf to make printing code evaluate to boolean. Not sure if there's a way to automate inserting this code into a breakpoint.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This is I was looking for. However it would be nice withouth the need of an conditional breakpoint. An option like "print systrace on breakpoint" would be cool

Comment: not working with eclipse Neon: "operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) void, null". The condition should be `System.out.printf(...); return false;`