# Create breakpoint when a specific method is called

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I'm working on a Java legacy code (in Eclipse). It works fine (its output is correct); however, it prints an extra blank line. I want to find this statement and remove it, but there are lots of `System.out.print` lines in the code and I cannot check them one by one. Is there any way to ask the Eclipse debugger to pause when `System.out.print` is called? It's similar to putting breakpoints on every `System.out.print` in the code (and the debugger will stop when it reaches these lines).

Comment: I think it is impossible..

Comment: I'm not sure how debuggers work entirely, but if they can execute codes step by step (or bytecode by bytecode), it seems feasible to specify a method (or its signature) and set a trigger after it's called.

Comment: in some ide like `xcode`, symbolic breakpoint is what you want. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13806200/how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-objectatindex-method-of-a-specific-property-in-a-s. But I don't know if eclipse has such features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think just set breakpoint on System.out#print method should work fine.
jdk source code:

```
public void println(String x) {
    synchronized (this) {
        print(x);  // break point here
        newLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's possible. But to tackle your problem, you can see the System.out.println statement above the blank line and add a breakpoint there.

This way you'll be able to get to the line faster.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you search in the code the line value? I mean, something like ctrl + f -> system.out.println(" ') //or whatever it prints. And then comment all the resulting lines.

I know that maybe it's lame, but sometimes the solution is simplier than it looks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use conditional breakpoint. You can check [this](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/help/html/setting_breakpoints.htm) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756874/eclipse-breakpoint-system-out) might also help.